# Como pegar somente uma coluna em uma grid freestyle no genexus ev03

Tags: genexus

Boa tarde galera,

Eu tenho uma grid freestyle na minha tela e dentro dela um atributo. Atributo Órgão por exemplo. Porem a hora que compilo o select gerado coloca mais uma outra coluna no select, que é o id. ficando no caso:

```
SELECT id, orgao from secretarias
```

Tem algum jeito de trazer somente a coluna ÓRGAO?

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não, não é possível. GeneXus sempre adiciona o campo de chave primária.